# Remove ".txt" from filename variable

Tags: c++, qt

I want to save some files with QT:

`QString path = SAVE_AUDIO_PATH+filename+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");`

`filename` have a format audiotest.txt

I want to delete a ending of filename - change from `audiotest.txt -> audiotest`

How can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The right way to get rid of the file extension is using `QFileInfo` class. For example:

```
auto fileNameWithoutExtension = QFileInfo(fileName).baseName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume there is always an extension, you can use:

```
filename.left( filename.lastIndexOf( '.' ) )
```

Otherwise, you would have to check to see if it has an extension or not first.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against doing it that way (and using @vahancho's suggestion with `baseName()` instead, as the implementation is rather brittle

Comment: It starts with a caveat. I haven't tested it, but it's also likely much faster.